# How do i install ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: windows-7

My problem is that i had already installed it in a pendrive, but i formated my lap top and the pendrive, i didn't uninstall ubuntu. When i finished installing the new OS i installed ubuntu again in the pendrive. When i tried to update ubuntu i had problems and i decided to download the latest version. I formated the pendrive again, but when i tried to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS the installer told me that i have already intalled ubuntu and the installation can't advance. Also when i turn on my computer when i have to select an OS there are two ubuntu options, how do i get rid of that?

Comment: so do you want directly to boot into windows without grub loader?

Comment: yes, and i also want to intall ubuntu 12.04 in my pendrive

Comment: I am posting the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to reinstall the MBR of windows to boot directly into windows. Now when you got your one problem solved, the other has a quick way around. First, to reinstal the MBR, you can use any windows cd/USB and just start repairing the windows(Windows Repair mode, they call it windows RE mode). Now when you got there, open the command prompt at windows RE mode. I am sure you can open up the command prompt,if not then google for it.

Now at the command prompt, start typing as illustrated:

```
x:\sources>bootrec /fixmbr
x:\sources>bootrec /fixboot //Well only "/fixmbr" can do the whole thing for you, this was for the worst case
```

Now this is how you can boot directly into windows. Now you have many utilities to install linux to USB, in windows. Now this will solve all your problems. 
**PS**- Do not forget to make it answer(if it really helped you) for it can remove my hassle to re-answer some other person for same concern.

Comment: i just did that but when i turn on my computer it stills opens the win 7 boot administrator with the ubuntu options

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the ubuntu partition? Just wipe everything exept Windows. Then can you just install ubuntu again or stick with Windows. The ubuntu site have a great site on how to use usb memory as a live cd.

[Ubuntu.com install ubuntu on usb drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)